# Git switch branch, lost untracked files

Tags: git

I have been working on a project where I've been mainly using a master branch, but there was also a dev branch I made that hasn't had much done on it. I switched to that branch and switched back to Master, only to find that all my untracked files were no longer in my repo (.env files, data folder and everything in it, config.json file).

It seems like when I switched branches my repo changed and discarded everything in .gitignore. Is there any way to recover all these files?

Comment: When switching branches, Git will leave all the files that are listed in your .gitignore, so they shouldn't have been affected. Are you sure they're not there?

Comment: You did something else besides just switch branches if you lost all your untracked files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I switched to that [`dev`] branch and switched back to `master` ...

Most likely, those files—untracked in `master`, and listed in `.gitignore`—are *present* in the tip commit of `dev`.

Doing:

```
git checkout dev
```

tells your Git: *Replace my index and work-tree contents with those from the commit to which `dev` points.*  Your Git therefore finds all the files that are frozen into that particular commit, extracts them from that commit, puts them into your index, and de-Git-ifies (thaws out and uncompresses) them into your work-tree.

This naturally overwrites the *untracked* files in your work-tree.  But that's no big deal, right?  They're in the commit.

Then you tell Git: *Replace my index and work-tree contents with those from the commit to which `master` points.*  Your Git therefore finds all the files that are frozen into the commit at the tip of `master`, extracts them, and puts them into your index and work-tree as before.  This time, those files *aren't* in the commit.  But they're tracked, and match the committed copies, so Git *removes* them.

And now they're gone!

You can get them out of the commit at the tip of `dev`, without also making them tracked, using `git show`:

```
git show dev:file > file
```

This extracts whatever is at the commit identified by `dev`, producing the output to stdout, which you redirect to the file.  The unfortunate part here is that it gets you whatever is *frozen into that commit*, which doesn't necessarily match what was *in your work-tree* when you ran `git checkout dev` originally.

Quite often, Git will warn you about this at one of the steps.  If you pay attention to these warnings and move the files out of the way, you have the moved-out-of-the-way copies.  But listing files in `.gitignore` has the side effect of, in certain cases, giving Git *permission to clobber their contents*.  So there are a few corner cases where Git will wipe out the current contents, assuming that because the files are `.gitignore`d, they're not precious in any way.

The only way to recover such files is outside Git, using, e.g., Time Machine on a Mac, or system backups.

Comment: So in particular, I have a virtualenv `venv` folder that is in .gitignore. `venv` is in a folder `new_project/`.  `new_projects/`+ it's contents were created and tracked under `dev` branch only. Switching to `master` makes `new_project` disappear. It seems like any sort of merging of `dev` branch and `master` will also eliminate my untracked `venv` folder?

Comment: Anything that forces Git to put `venv/*` files *into* the index causes those files to become tracked, because the definition of "tracked" is "a file that exists in the index". Anything that subsequently *removes* index entries under the names `venv/*` causes those files to be removed from the work-tree as well. So if you want to know: *will action X touch my `venv/*` files?* you can translate that question into: *does action X put a `venv/*` file into the index?*

Comment: The `git merge` command, or anything that performs a merge actions such as `git revert` or `git cherry-pick`, operates in the index, and does indeed put files (from all three commits that are the three inputs to the merge) into the index. This is the most complicated case since this uses the higher staging slots (slots 1-3) for each file, but the general rule will keep you safe: if this is going to touch a `venv/*` file in the index, move your existing untracked `venv/*` files out of the way first.

Comment: Note that if they're all in one subdirectory like this, the moving is easy: `mv venv venv.save`. Do the Git operation, finish it, clean up, and make sure `venv/*` are no longer relevant or no longer exist, then remove the directory if needed and then `mv venv.save venv`.

Comment: Another case where Git's obtuse UX causes issues, in this case significant ones.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact situation and discovered a solution from someone using "git stash" that worked like a charm.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Try:

```
git stash list
```

From the stash list, select the stash@{number}.  Let's say 5 as an example to see what are the contents from that point (it may be a different number where your untracked files are stashed).

```
git stash show --include-untracked stash@{5}
```

After you see your missing files, you can recover them using "git apply" which is like "git pop" except it doesn't remove the state from the stash list.  Make sure you first commit any new changes and backup all your files!

```
git stash apply stash@{5}
```

If you happen to encounter merge errors, just commit those files then try the last step again.

And voila, your files are back!